# Differentiable function only on $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ with extendable derivative.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I'm looking for a example of a continuous functions $f:\mathbb R\longrightarrow \mathbb R$  differentiable only in $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ such that $f(0)=0$ and $f'$, defined in $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$, can be defined in $x=0$, and this extension of $f'$ is continuous in $\mathbb R$. I know that any example with $f'(0)=0$ will not work, because in this case we can prove that $f$ is differentiable in $0$. Any suggestions?

Comment: Given that what you say about $f'(0) = 0$ is true, you can always consider a function $f(x) - k x$ for any $k \in \mathbb R$. If you ever encounter a sought-for function, just set $k = f'(0)$, and you'll get and example with zero derivative.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and differentiable everywhere except at $0$. Suppose that $f'$ is continuous at $0$. In fact, $f$ is differentiable at $0$. Using the mean value theorem, we know that for every $x\in \mathbb{R}^*$, there exists $c_x \in ]0,x[$ such that

$$f'(c_x)=\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}.$$

But by hypothesis, $\lim_{x\to 0}f'(c_x)$ exists. Consequently, thanks to the definition of differentiability at $0$, we get that $f$ is differentiable at $0$.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such example. If $f$ is continuous, differentiable except at the origin, and $\lim_{t\to0}f'(t)$ exists then $f$ is differentiable at the origin. You can prove this by the Mean Value Theorem.